# Git settting up a Typescript development and pushing only compiled files

Tags: typescript, git, github

Am using *Typescript* for development and want to push only compiled files to public repository. What I did was start new project created a **deploy** folder this will be where all compiled files will be placed and what gets pushed to Repo. Then I added an empty *.gitignore* file created a commit on *master-branch* and created a new Branch called *Development* switched to it and created a folder called **Src** to hold all typescript files also added the **deploy** folder to the *.gitignore* and committed the changes to *development-branch*.

Project structure:

```
 deploy/
 src/
 .gitignore
```

The idea i work on *development-branc*h compile files they get added to deploy folder switch to *master-branch* and commit whats get placed in deploy folder. Question is there a better way and if my way will cause problems..thanks

Comment: If `src` and `deploy` will be pushed to different remotes I'd go with two separate repositories, not two branches. Other than that the plan looks ok for me. I use similar setup myself: I generate docs for Cheeta3 from [the source in the master repository](https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/cheetah3/tree/master/docs), commit regenerated docs [to a separate repo](https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/cheetahtemplate3.github.io) and push generated docs to [Github Pages](https://cheetahtemplate3.github.io/).

Answer (score 1):

I see no principal problems in doing this<sup>1</sup>.

You probably want to have `deploy` common to both branches though. In theory you could keep it exclusive for `Development`, but the challenge then is that when you switch between branches where one of them tracks files in a directory and the other does not you risk git refusing switching branches because it would overwrite untracked files and similar problems.

---

<sup>1</sup> It sounds somewhat similar to what I do for my [git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3](https://github.com/hlovdal/git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3) project where `main` is the development branch and I then have two branches `runtime-unix` and `runtime-windows` that can be used for "deployment".

Comment: What if I delete everything in deploy folder while on master-branch since files in it are just generated from development-branch create a commit, then switch to development branch do some work and compile files into deploy folder, then switch to master-branch amend the new compiled files and deploy...and keep doing that will there be a conflict.thanks